# How to merge pdfs(Alive PDF) in flex3?

Tags: apache-flex

My flex application generates individual pdf documents based on individual selection criterion,but i need to merge those generated pdfs or is it possible to store individual pdfs temporarily then  merge those into single pdf?

Answer (score 1):

small logic,  call save() method of PDF object after all myPDF.addGrid() methods, then it will be saved in to one pdf file generated

```
var myPDF:PDF = new PDF(Orientation.PORTRAIT, Unit.MM, Size.A4);

 for(each array )
 {
      var grid:Grid = new Grid(...);
      grid.columns = pdfGridColumn;
      myPDF.addGrid(grid)
 }
```

finally call 
myPDF.save();

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just store the data, and when comes the time to 'merge', have both datasets create your pdf?

I think that merging PDF documents together is out of AlivePDF's scope.  You might have to revert to a server side technology if you want to do it.